# How to Write a MDX Query with Date Range and Rows Filters

Tags: mdx, pentaho, olap

I need to write an MDX query that filters in the WHERE by a date range and rows by "esquema" columns.

The query separately for the date range or the "esquema" column works well. example by date range:

```
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Importe]} ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY 
   Crossjoin([Bancos].[All Bancoss].Children, 
     Crossjoin([Fechas de Cobro].[All Fechas de Cobros].Children, 
       Crossjoin([Fechas de Emisión].[All Fechas de Emisións].Children, 
         Crossjoin([Destinatarios].[All Destinatarioss].Children, 
           Crossjoin([Comprobantes].[All Comprobantess].Children, [Conceptos].[All Conceptoss].Children))))) ON ROWS 
FROM [Cubrir Bancos] 
WHERE 
  (
    $['[Filtro Esquemas.Esquema]].[' 
      + (parameters.esquema!'All Filtro Esquemas.Esquemas') + ']]'], $['[Filtro Bancos.Banco]].[' 
      + (parameters.banco!'All Filtro Bancos.Bancos') + ']]'], $['[Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro]].[' 
      + (parameters.startDate!'All Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobros') + ']]'] : $['[Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro]].[' 
     + (parameters.endDate!'All Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobros') + ']]']
  )
```

and filter by rows only:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Importe]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY Crossjoin([Bancos].[All Bancoss].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Fechas de Cobro].[All Fechas de Cobros].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Fechas de Emisión].[All Fechas de Emisións].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Destinatarios].[All Destinatarioss].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Comprobantes].[All Comprobantess].Children, [Conceptos].[All Conceptoss].Children))))) ON ROWS 
FROM [Cubrir Bancos] 
WHERE ($['[Filtro Esquemas.Esquema]].[' + (parameters.esquema!'All Filtro Esquemas.Esquemas') + ']]'], 
       $['[Filtro Bancos.Banco]].[' + (parameters.banco!'All Filtro Bancos.Bancos') + ']]'])
```

but is not working when i put it together, the query is:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Importe]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY Crossjoin([Bancos].[All Bancoss].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Fechas de Cobro].[All Fechas de Cobros].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Fechas de Emisión].[All Fechas de Emisións].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Destinatarios].[All Destinatarioss].Children, 
          Crossjoin([Comprobantes].[All Comprobantess].Children, [Conceptos].[All Conceptoss].Children))))) ON ROWS 
FROM [Cubrir Bancos] 
WHERE ({$['[Filtro Esquemas.Esquema]].[' + (parameters.esquema!'All Filtro Esquemas.Esquemas') + ']]'], $['[Filtro Bancos.Banco]].[' + (parameters.banco!'All Filtro Bancos.Bancos') + ']]'], $['[Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro]].[' + (parameters.startDate!'All Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobros') + ']]'] : $['[Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro]].[' + (parameters.endDate!'All Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobros') + ']]']}
       $['[Filtro Esquemas.Esquema]].[' + (parameters.esquema!'All Filtro Esquemas.Esquemas') + ']]'], 
       $['[Filtro Bancos.Banco]].[' + (parameters.banco!'All Filtro Bancos.Bancos') + ']]']))
```

How would you do to use the 2 types of filter in MDX?

I'm using Pentaho 6 CE and Pivot4J.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro].[All].[dts] AS
  SUM(
    $['[Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro]].[' 
      + (parameters.startDate!'All Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobros') + ']]'] : $['[Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro]].[' 
     + (parameters.endDate!'All Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobros') + ']]']
  )
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Importe]} ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY 
   Crossjoin([Bancos].[All Bancoss].Children, 
     Crossjoin([Fechas de Cobro].[All Fechas de Cobros].Children, 
       Crossjoin([Fechas de Emisión].[All Fechas de Emisións].Children, 
         Crossjoin([Destinatarios].[All Destinatarioss].Children, 
           Crossjoin([Comprobantes].[All Comprobantess].Children, [Conceptos].[All Conceptoss].Children))))) ON ROWS 
FROM [Cubrir Bancos] 
WHERE 
(
  $['[Filtro Esquemas.Esquema]].[' + (parameters.esquema!'All Filtro Esquemas.Esquemas') + ']]']
, $['[Filtro Bancos.Banco]].[' + (parameters.banco!'All Filtro Bancos.Bancos') + ']]']
, $['[Filtro Esquemas.Esquema]].[' + (parameters.esquema!'All Filtro Esquemas.Esquemas') + ']]']
, $['[Filtro Bancos.Banco]].[' + (parameters.banco!'All Filtro Bancos.Bancos') + ']]']
, [Filtro Fechas.Fecha de Cobro].[All].[dts]
);
```